# Android WebView - Load Images from cache

Tags: android, caching, webview

My webview saves lot of cache on SD Card when I visit a site which contains images and they don't show their format. When I try to open them, the default Android file manager says "File type not found". Then I changed the format of some of them(mostly the big size one) to .jpg and bingo, they are the images I saw on the webpage.

Punchline: I want to open the images from that sites that are saved as cache, in another activity, would I have to go on and rename all the cache files to .jpg then call them or there is another way to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: How are you open and displaying that images?

Comment: In the file manager? Just renamed then, added .jpg to their original name. In the app? don't know, that's what I want to know, how to display them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) to open these images files. You can try:

```
- decodeFile(String pathName)
```

If it gives some problem with the extension, try `decodeStream (InputStream is)`, it receive an `InputStream` and it should work.

---

You can list a folder with File:

```
File f = new File(Environment
          .getExternalStorageDirectory()
          .getAbsolutePath());

File[] files = f.listFiles();
for (File file : files){
   //Do something with this file
}
```

Comment: decodeFile seems promising, but here pathName is the exact path of the cache and the cache have random name,is there some other code which takes whole directory into consideration?